# Using RTK createAsyncThunk function as Promise.all

Tags: typescript, redux, es6-promise, redux-toolkit

If i call the createAsyncThunk function multiple times within a component, each store is updated individually, causing frequent re-rendering.
Even if you try to update the store all at once using the createAsyncThunk function using Promsie.all, individual updates will proceed.
How can I batch store updates at once?

```
const getToken = createAsyncThunk('getToken', async() => {
    // return axios.get()
})


export const tokenMiddleware = (store: any) => (next: any) => (action: any) => { 
    const {type, payload, meta} = action
      switch (type) {
        case 'getToken/fulfilled':
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'anothetStore/update',
            payload: payload.data1
        })
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'anothetStore2/update',
            payload: payload.data2
        })
     // other status updates
}

const getPermissions = createAsyncThunk('getPermissions', async() => {
    // return axios.get()
})

export const permissionMiddleware = (store: any) => (next: any) => (action: any) => { 
    const {type, payload, meta} = action
      switch (type) {
        case 'getPermissions/fulfilled':
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'anothetStore/update',
            payload: payload.data1
        })
         store.dispatch({
            type: 'anothetStore2/update',
            payload: payload.data2
        })

}

const authorization = createAsyncThunk('authorization', async (_, api) => {
   try {
      const result = await Promise.all([
         api.dispatch(getToken()),
         api.dispatch(getPermissions()),
      ]);

   }catch(err) {
   // error handling
   }  
});
```

The reason for using middleware is that the store must be updated sequentially in order.
So I tried using redux's batch function, but it didn't update all at once, and re-rendering occurred every time each store was updated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to render only once after dispatching the `authorization` thunk, is that right?

Comment: @LinDu yes that's right !